# Automate tick max and min in faceted ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to just mark the max and min of each x-axis in a faceted ggplot. I have several facets with different x scales and the same y scale, and the x axis tick labels overlap each other. Rather than having to manually determine the limits and breaks for each facet x axis, I am looking for a way to just label the min and max values for each.

Code using example data of the `CO2` dataset (see `?CO2`):

```
CO2$num <- 1:nrow(CO2)
library(reshape2)
CO2.melt <- melt(CO2,
                 id.var=c("Type",
                          "Plant",
                          "Treatment",
                          "num"))
CO2.melt <- CO2.melt[order(CO2.melt$num),]

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(CO2.melt, 
       aes(x = value, 
           y = num)) +
  geom_path(aes(color = Treatment)) +
  facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales = "free_x",nrow=1)
```

[image]

Purpose is to replicate well log displays such as [this one](http://certmapper.cr.usgs.gov/data/PubArchives/OF00-200/WELLS/TULAGEA1/LAS/TL1LOG.JPG).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to add larger labels for min and max on top of the existing labels? Or do you want to remove the other labels and only keep min and max? And should the labels be coloured?

Comment: @Stibu, I'm looking to just label the min and max, without the existing labels. I was in a rush to make the figure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you want to implemented this for the tick-labels, the use of `scales = "free_x"` in a faceted plot makes this hard to automate this. However, with a bit of tinkering and the help of several other packages, you could also use the following approach:

**1)** Summarise the data in order to get an idea which tick-labels / breaks you need on the x-axis:

```
library(data.table)
minmax <- melt(setDT(CO2.melt)[, .(min.val = min(value), max.val = max(value),
                                   floor.end = 10*ceiling(min(value)/10),
                                   ceil.end = 10*floor((max(value)-1)/10)),
                               variable][],
               measure.vars = patterns('.val','.end'),
               variable.name = 'var',
               value.name = c('minmax','ends'))
```

which gives:

```
> minmax
   variable var minmax ends
1:     conc   1   95.0  100
2:   uptake   1    7.7   10
3:     conc   2 1000.0  990
4:   uptake   2   45.5   40
```

**2)** Create break vecors for each facet:

```
brks1 <- c(95,250,500,750,1000)
brks2 <- c(7.7,10,20,30,40,45.5)
```

**3)** Create the facets:

```
p1 <- ggplot(CO2.melt[CO2.melt$variable=="conc",], 
             aes(x = value, y = num, colour = Treatment)) +
  geom_path() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = brks1) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = c('red','black')[c(1,2,2,2,1)],
                                   face = c('bold','plain')[c(1,2,2,2,1)]),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey60"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(CO2.melt[CO2.melt$variable=="uptake",], 
             aes(x = value, y = num, colour = Treatment)) +
  geom_path() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = brks2) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = c('red','black')[c(1,2,2,2,2,1)],
                                   face = c('bold','plain')[c(1,2,2,2,2,1)]),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey60"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

**4)** Extract the legend into a separate object:

```
library(grid)
library(gtable)
fill.legend <- gtable_filter(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2)), "guide-box")
legGrob <- grobTree(fill.legend)
```

**5)** Create the final plot:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1 + theme(legend.position="none"), 
             p2 + theme(legend.position="none"), 
             legGrob, ncol=3, widths = c(4,4,1))
```

which results in:

[image]

---

A possible alternative solution to do this automatically, is either use `geom_text` or `geom_label`. An example to show how you can achieve this:

```
# create a summary
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
minmax <- CO2.melt %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  summarise(minx = min(value), maxx = max(value)) %>%
  gather(lbl, val, -1)

# create the plot
ggplot(CO2.melt, aes(x = value, y = num, color = Treatment)) +
  geom_path() +
  geom_text(data = minmax, 
            aes(x = val, y = -3, label = val), 
            colour = "red", fontface = "bold", size = 5) +
  facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales = "free_x", nrow=1) +
  theme_minimal()
```

which gives:

[image]

You can also get the minimum and maximum values on the fly inside `ggplot` (credit to [@eipi10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35923085/2204410)). Another example using `geom_label`:

```
ggplot(CO2.melt, aes(x = value, y = num, color = Treatment)) +
  geom_path() +
  geom_label(data = CO2.melt %>% 
               group_by(variable) %>% 
               summarise(minx = min(value), maxx = max(value)) %>%
               gather(lbl, val, -1), 
             aes(x = val, y = -3, label = val), 
             colour = "red", fontface = "bold", size = 5) +
  facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales = "free_x", nrow=1) +
  theme_minimal()
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm using a variation of your second solution. It becomes more difficult to fit things with more panels, but that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit** Updating to ggplot2 ver 3.0.0

This approach modifies the labels in the ggplot build data (i.e., `ggplot_build(plot)`). I've removed the x-axis expansions so that the maximum and minimum values fall on the panel boundaries.

```
# Packages
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# Data
CO2$num <- 1:nrow(CO2)
library(reshape2)
CO2.melt <- melt(CO2,
                 id.var=c("Type",
                          "Plant",
                          "Treatment",
                          "num"))
CO2.melt <- CO2.melt[order(CO2.melt$num),]

# Plot
(p <- ggplot(CO2.melt, 
       aes(x = value, 
           y = num)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  geom_path(aes(color = Treatment)) +
  facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales = "free_x", nrow=1)) 

# Get the build data
gb <- ggplot_build(p)

# Get number of panels
panels = length(gb$layout$panel_params)

# Get x tick mark labels
x.labels = lapply(1:panels, function(N)   gb$layout$panel_params[[N]]$x.labels)

# Get range of x values
x.range = lapply(1:panels, function(N) gb$layout$panel_params[[N]]$x.range)

# Get position of x tick mark labels
x.pos = lapply(1:panels, function(N) gb$layout$panel_params[[N]]$x.major)

# Get new x tick mark labels - includes max and min
new.labels = lapply(1:panels, function(N) as.character(sort(unique(c(as.numeric(x.labels[[N]]), x.range[[N]])))))

# Tag min and max values with "min" and "max"
new.labelsC = new.labels
minmax = c("min", "max")
new.labelsC = lapply(1:panels, function(N) {
   x = c(new.labelsC[[N]][1], new.labelsC[[N]][length(new.labels[[N]])])
   x = paste0(x, "\n", minmax)
   c(x[1], new.labelsC[[N]][2:(length(new.labels[[N]])-1)], x[2])
} )

# # Get position of new labels
new.pos = lapply(1:panels, function(N) (as.numeric(new.labels[[N]]) - x.range[[N]][1])/(x.range[[N]][2] - x.range[[N]][1]))

# Put them back into the build data
for(i in 1:panels) {
   gb$layout$panel_params[[i]]$x.labels = new.labelsC[[i]]
   gb$layout$panel_params[[i]]$x.major_source = as.numeric(new.labels[[i]])
   gb$layout$panel_params[[i]]$x.major = new.pos[[i]]
}

# Get the ggplot grob
gp = ggplot_gtable(gb)

# Add some additional space between the panels
pos = gp$layout$l[grep("panel", gp$layout$name)] # Positions of the panels
for(i in 1:(panels-1)) gp$widths[[pos[i]+1]] = unit(1, "cm")

# Colour the min and max labels using `grid` editing functions
for(i in 1:panels) {
   gp = editGrob(grid.force(gp), gPath(paste0("axis-b-", i), "axis", "axis", "GRID.text"), 
         grep = TRUE, gp = gpar(col = c("red", rep("black", length(new.labels[[i]])-2), "red")))
}

# Draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gp)
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I really need to learn more about the `ggplot_build` stuff :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thought to share this as I needed something similar. Here is a simpler way to print the minimum and maximum values to each facet. I am uncertain, however, how to change the color of min/max axis text values. Perhaps that is not needed in all applications.

```r
library(ggplot2); library(reshape2)

data(CO2)
CO2$num <- 1:nrow(CO2)

CO2.melt <- reshape2::melt(CO2,
                 id.var=c("Type",
                          "Plant",
                          "Treatment",
                          "num"))

CO2.melt <- CO2.melt[order(CO2.melt$num),]

ggplot(CO2.melt, 
       aes(x = value, 
           y = num)) +
  geom_path(aes(color = Treatment)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = function(k) {
    sort(unique(c(
      pretty(range(k)),
      round(unname(quantile(k, c(0,1))))
    )))
    }
    ) +
  facet_wrap( ~ variable, scales = "free_x",nrow=1) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(2, "lines"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>