# How to add space above and below ylim in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was wondering how I would add more space above and below the y min and y max using ggplot in r. A picture below shows what the current situation is, but I want more space above the top number and below the bottom one.

[image]

Comment: I have updated the question with a new one please take a look @Winter

Comment: [avoiding axis tick label collision in faceted ggplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41575045/avoiding-axis-tick-label-collision-in-faceted-ggplots)

Comment: that helps but is insanely complicated to fix something so simple

Comment: If you want simplicity, you could use `theme(panel.spacing.y = unit(2, "lines"))` or something similar. But I thought that increasing the panel spacing was not an option (though that message seems to have disappeared).

Answer (score 0):

I got this directly from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762287/how-can-i-format-axis-labels-with-exponents-with-ggplot2-and-scales): I think this will answer your question.

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- 1:4
y <- c(0, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003)

dd <- data.frame(x, y)

scientific_10 <- function(x) {
  parse(text=gsub("e", " %*% 10^", scales::scientific_format()(x)))
}

ggplot(dd, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()+scale_y_continuous(label=scientific_10)
```